# Insert values with PL/SQL Tables and Record

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have done a procedure in a package to enter data into a table using a PL / SQL table.

I have put some data in the code to execute from the package and verify that the procedure works, but I don't know how to execute it from the worksheet with the data that i enter.

```
CREATE TABLE TB_CRUD_MAC
   (    "K_CODIGO" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "A_NUMNIT" VARCHAR2(11 BYTE), 
    "N_NOMBRE" VARCHAR2(11 BYTE), 
    "N_APELLI" VARCHAR2(11 BYTE), 
    "F_FECHA" DATE, 
    "I_ESTADO" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "K_CLASIF" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
   )
```

```
create or replace PACKAGE PK_CRUD_MAC AS

   TYPE R_REGISTRO IS RECORD (
     codigo TB_CRUD_MAC.K_CODIGO%TYPE := K_CODIGO.nextval,
     numnit TB_CRUD_MAC.A_NUMNIT%TYPE,
     nombre TB_CRUD_MAC.N_NOMBRE%TYPE,
     apelli TB_CRUD_MAC.N_APELLI%TYPE,
     fecha TB_CRUD_MAC.F_FECHA%TYPE,
     estado TB_CRUD_MAC.I_ESTADO%TYPE,
     clasif TB_CRUD_MAC.K_CLASIF%TYPE
     );

   TYPE T_REGISTRO IS TABLE OF R_REGISTRO;

   PROCEDURE PR_INSERT_LISTA (PT_REGISTRO IN OUT T_REGISTRO);   
END;
```

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PK_CRUD_MAC AS

    PROCEDURE PR_INSERT_LISTA (PT_REGISTRO IN OUT T_REGISTRO)

    IS

      BEGIN

      PT_REGISTRO := T_REGISTRO();
      PT_REGISTRO.extend(3);
      PT_REGISTRO(1).nombre :=  'Andres';
      PT_REGISTRO(2).nombre :=  'Martinez';

      INSERT INTO TB_CRUD_MAC VALUES (K_CODIGO.nextval, '123', PT_REGISTRO(1).nombre, 'AAA', '28/03/00', '1', '1');
      INSERT INTO TB_CRUD_MAC VALUES (K_CODIGO.nextval, '123', PT_REGISTRO(2).nombre, 'AAA', '28/03/00', '1', '1');

      END;

END;
```

Edit:
I try this but dont work:

```
DECLARE
reg PK_CRUD_MAC.T_REGISTRO := PK_CRUD_MAC.T_REGISTRO();
BEGIN
reg().extend;
reg(1).nombre := 'AAA';
PK_CRUD_MAC.PR_INSERT_LISTA(reg);
END;
```

Error: **PLS-00355: use of pl/sql table not allowed in this context**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a cursor like you had in mind, does not work. try this:

```
DECLARE

    reg PK_CRUD_MAC.T_REGISTRO := PK_CRUD_MAC.T_REGISTRO();
BEGIN
    reg.extend;
    reg(1).numnit := 'Aaa';
    reg(1).nombre := 'aaa';
    PK_CRUD_MAC.PR_INSERT_LISTA(reg);

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Well running your procedure is simply a matter of declaring a variable and calling the procedure, say in an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
declare
  l_table pk_crud_mac.t_registro;
begin
   pk_crud_mac.pr_insert_lista(l_table);
end;
/
```

However, this doesn't get us very far. Probably you don't want to have those values hard-coded in the procedure. Instead you should populate the values in the calling program and pass them to the procedure.

Oh, and defaulting `R_REGISTRO.codigo` to a sequence value may seem like a neat idea but it can cause problems with initialisation. It's probably better to handle K_CODIGO.nextval in the internals of the code.

So, re-writing your package like this ...

```
create or replace package pk_crud_mac as

   type r_registro is record (
     codigo tb_crud_mac.k_codigo%type,
     numnit tb_crud_mac.a_numnit%type,
     nombre tb_crud_mac.n_nombre%type,
     apelli tb_crud_mac.n_apelli%type,
     fecha tb_crud_mac.f_fecha%type,
     estado tb_crud_mac.i_estado%type,
     clasif tb_crud_mac.k_clasif%type
     );

   type t_registro is table of r_registro;

   procedure pr_insert_lista (pt_registro in out t_registro);   

end;
/

create or replace package body pk_crud_mac as

    procedure pr_insert_lista (pt_registro in out t_registro)
    is
    begin

      for idx in pt_registro.first()..pt_registro.last loop
        pt_registro(idx).codigo := k_codigo.nextval;
      end loop;

      forall idx in pt_registro.first()..pt_registro.last
        insert into tb_crud_mac values pt_registro(idx);

      end;

end;
/
```

...means we call it like this:

```
declare
  l_record pk_crud_mac.r_registro;
  l_table  pk_crud_mac.t_registro := new  pk_crud_mac.t_registro();
begin

  l_record.nombre :=  'Andres';
  l_record.numnit := '123';
  l_record.apelli := 'AAA';
  l_record.fecha  := date '2000-03-28';
  l_record.estado := '1';
  l_record.clasif := '1'; 

  l_table.extend();
  l_table(l_table.count()) := l_record;

  l_record.nombre :=  'Martinez';

  l_table.extend();
  l_table(l_table.count()) := l_record;

  pk_crud_mac.pr_insert_lista(l_table);

  for idx in 1..l_table.count() loop
    dbms_output.put_line(l_table(idx).codigo ||':' || l_table(idx).nombre);
  end loop;

end;
/
```

If you enable SERVEROUTPUT the call to `dbms_output.put_line` will show you that the sequence value has been assigned to each record.